# nokia csv file import issue in php

Tags: php, csv, import

```
Title,"First name","Middle name","Last name","address"
Mr.,"prince","M","Kachhadiya","A-42,AdarshNagar-2     c.g Road, "
```

Address field have value like **"A-42,AdarshNagar-2     ChhpraBhatha Road,"** this value have comma(,)  in between and csv file default field separator is comma(,) so it will assume **A-42** and **AdarshNagar-2     c.g Road** as different field value. 
how can i resolve it?

My Php Code:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       // Code for parse csv data
}
```

Comment: Your test works fine for me. The commas are inside a quoted string, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

use fgetcsv() to read from a file . Refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
Title,"First name","Middle name","Last name","address"
Mr.,"prince","M","Kachhadiya","A-42,AdarshNagar-2    c.g Road,"

//You can't split the strings using CSV functions so better do some manual work

//All csv values are quoted with double quotes so split the string like this

//**If file size is minimum use this function**

$data = file_get_contents('<file_path>');

$parsed_string = explode('",', $data);

$cnt = count($parsed_string);

for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{   
    $value = substr($parsed_string,1);
}

//**If file size is maximum use this**

$file = fopen("<file path>","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
    $data = fgets($file);

    $parsed_string = explode('",', $data);

    $cnt = count($parsed_string);

    for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
    {

        $value = substr($parsed_string,1);
    }
  }

fclose($file);
```